# How to bundle chromedriver.exe with Electron app

Tags: selenium, electron, selenium-chromedriver, electron-builder, electron-packager

Apologies if this has been asked, but after researching I couldn't find an answer to my question.

I am working on a desktop electron app that runs selenium scripts for the purpose of automating tedious/repetitive tasks. I know how to bundle and distribute my source code, but I want to package the chromedriver.exe to C:\Windows with the installation and to change the system environment variable to reference that on windows.

The people who will be using the program are very tech illiterate, so I want to make this very seamless. Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: This is typically the task of the installer which will install your app to the system. Do you have any plans on this? Letting Electron copy the file over to `C:\Windows` upon first run does not seem like a particularly good idea.

Comment: Yes you're correct, I want that to occur when the user installs the application